# Update Text Multiple Action Buttons - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Here is the scenario:

I have a data frame named `stories` generated by a function called say `abc()` of the following type:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 a  e  i  m  q
2 b  f  j  n  r
3 c  g  k  o  s
4 d  h  l  p  t
```

Now I have given in the ui.r 5 action buttons say (Action 1,..., Action 5)

Now when a user selects Action 1 I want to display `stories[,1]` similarly for others like Action 5 displays `stories[,5]`

To achieve this I have written an `If` statement unfortunately this only yields values based ONLY on what is last in my last `if` condition

Below is the server.R code:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input,output,session){
            abc()
    terms<-reactive({
      if(input$analyse5){
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Analyzing")
          stories[,5]
        })
      })}
      if(input$analyse4){
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Analyzing")
          stories[,4]
        })
      })}
    if(input$analyse3){
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Analyzing")
          stories[,3]
        })
      })}
    if(input$analyse2){
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Analyzing")
          stories[,2]
        })
      })}
    if(input$analyse1){
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Analyzing")
          stories[,1]
        })
      })}
    })

    output$text1<-renderUI({
      HTML(paste(h2(terms()[1]),terms()[2],terms()[3],terms()[4],sep='<br/><br/>'))
    })
  }
)
```

Firstly only when I press the first action button it triggers `[a,b,c,d]` If any other action button is pressed first it yields nothing, similarly after the first Action Button is pressed and then other action Buttons it doesnot show respective columns in stories i.e. say Action 2 does not give `stories[,2]=[e,f,g,h]` instead it remains as `[a,b,c,d]` ideally which means the buttons are not responding

Below is the ui.r for your reference as well:

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage((
    titlePanel('Some Headline')),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("analyse1","Action 1"),
        actionButton("analyse2","Action 2"),
        actionButton("analyse3","Action 3"),
        actionButton("analyse4","Action 4"),
        actionButton("analyse5","Action 5")
        ),
   mainPanel(
        h4(htmlOutput("text1"))
      ))))
```

Edit: Tried using `observeEvent`

section of modified code:

```
terms<-reactive({
      observeEvent((input$analyse5),{
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Loading 5th Article...")
          stories[,5]
        })
      })})
      observeEvent((input$analyse4),{
      isolate({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Loading 4th Article...")
          stories[,4]
        })
      })})
```

This is improved the situation: earlier I could see that all the action buttons were executing simultaneously (The Progress message of every scenario triggering) now i see only the respective button progress message on a click of the button, but am not able to get the output, it still remains that of the first one.

Please Help With Some Code Examples.

Update: When I add print(stories[,5]) or print(stories[,4]), it prints on the console for the click of the respective button but not on the Shiny App.

Comment: I would recommend defining an object with `reactiveValues`, then have each of the acroom buttons tied to an `observeEvent`, each of which modified the reactive value appropriately

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin for the reply, I am struggling a bit, can you please write me some dummy code that can help? Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full working app.  I just got in to a computer, so I wasn't able to submit it sooner.  I submit it in case you still find it useful.

```
library(shiny)

stories <- matrix(letters[1:20], byrow = FALSE, nrow = 4)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        titlePanel('Some Headline'),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          actionButton("analyse1","Action 1"),
          actionButton("analyse2","Action 2"),
          actionButton("analyse3","Action 3"),
          actionButton("analyse4","Action 4"),
          actionButton("analyse5","Action 5")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          h4(htmlOutput("text1"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
      Terms <- reactiveValues(
        Selection = 1
      )

      # using an observe block lets us listen for multiple events
      # without having to rewrite the code five times
      observe({
        lapply(sprintf("analyse%s", 1:5),
               function(x)
               {
                 observeEvent(input[[x]],
                              Terms$Selection <- as.numeric(sub("analyse", "", x)))
               })
      })

      output$text1<-renderUI({
        HTML(paste(stories[, Terms$Selection],collapse='<br/><br/>'))
      })

    })
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin you are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

With hints from @Benjamin I was able to solve this:

Here are the changes that worked (sampled code):

```
terms<-reactiveValues(dta = NULL)

observeEvent(input$analyse1,{
            withProgress({
              setProgress(message = "Loading 1st Article...")
            terms$dta<-stories[,1]
          })
          })
```

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I was recommending.